# angular hide button if objects object array contains key

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Lets say there is an object(game) that has an array with objects(players) and if the player array has a certain value(_id) that equals the current value I want to hide a button(join).

game object:

```
    {
        "_id":"123459595",
        "players":[
            {
            "_id":"some_id",
            "name":"some_username"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I know I can hide the button like:

```
<button ng-hide="playerJoined">Join game</button>
```

Where playerJoined is a statement that checks if the players is in the array. I have acces to the current player value from the variable currentPlayer that is available from the $rootScope.

How should I check if the currentPlayer exists as a value in the array with players?

[Fiddle of example (without the right check).](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5154/)

Comment: Do you have a plunker for this?

Comment: @jsmtslch added a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5155/ <br>
So I added condition in your ng-hide. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: @jsmtslch no i want to check if the curretnPlayer value is in the player array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ng-hide on a `$scope.inGame()` function that checks `$scope.game.players` for the given ID. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/mxhy0sdd/

P.S. Don't use $rootScope to share data between controllers :P I fixed this as well